# Gmail Script: Time of Day based filter

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Hoping someone could help me on this!

I have a scout alarm system with access sensors. Everytime a specific door is opened I would receive an email of that activity. Being that there are no time of day notifications from Scout, it's either on or off, I wanted to handle this at the email end using Google Apps Script for Gmail.

Monday through Friday - Any emails coming from the alert system before 8am and after 6PM should go to my Inbox, otherwise it should go to the trash.

Saturday through Sunday - All emails coming from the alert system should come to my inbox.

Please tell me this is possible!!!

-UPDATE-
Here is a beta code for this but it doesn't seem to be working. I get a flood of ALL messages in my Inbox at weird times, hopefully someone can help clean it up?

```
            function MoveMsgBasedOnTime() 
{
   //Enter the Label you created in your Google Apps Account for scout@#######.com
          var Label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("2 - Scout");

           //Retrieve All Messages with Matching Label 
         var Threads = Label.getThreads();
        for (var i = 0; i < Threads.length; i++) 
   {
    var Msgs = Threads[i].getMessages();

     for (var j=0;j < Msgs.length ;j++)
     {
     var MsgTime = new Date();
      MsgTime = Msgs[j].getDate();
       MsgTime.getDay();



       //Test For Day of Week

       //If Sunday (0) or Saturday (5)
       if (MsgTime.getDay() == 0 || MsgTime.getDay() == 6)
       {
         var test ="Weekend";
         //Move To Inbox
         Threads[i].moveToInbox();

       }

        //If Monday(1), Tuesday (2), Wednesday (3), Thursday (4), Friday (5)
        if (MsgTime.getDay() == 1 || MsgTime.getDay() == 2 || MsgTime.getDay() == 3 || MsgTime.getDay() == 4 || MsgTime.getDay() == 5 )
       {
         var test ="Weekday";


         // Time Interval To Delete Message
         var startTime = '8:00 AM';
         var endTime   = '7:30 PM';

         var now       = new Date();
         var startDate = dateObj(startTime);
         var endDate   = dateObj(endTime);
         var Label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("2 - Scout");

         var actionToTake = now < endDate && now > startDate ? 'delete' : 'move';

            //If Message Time is Between 8am and 6pm Take Action to Move to Trash
         if (actionToTake == "delete")
           ;

         //If Message Time is Before 8am or After 6pm Take Action to Move to Inbox
         if (actionToTake == "move")
           Threads[i].removeLabel(Label);
             Threads[i].moveToInbox();
       }
     }
    }
   }

                //Function To Parse Time from Date for Comparisson using startTime & endTime variables above
                function dateObj(d) 
             {
                       var parts = d.split(/:|\s/),
                      date  = new Date();
                   if (parts.pop().toLowerCase() == 'pm') parts[0] = (+parts[0]) + 12;
                  date.setHours(+parts.shift());
                  date.setMinutes(+parts.shift());
                 return date;
                   }
```

Comment: welcome to stack this isn't a website where we do work for you show us what youve attempted and we can help yo uwith your issues

Comment: I was hoping someone could enlighten me on how to approach this or direct me somewhere where I can request things of this nature?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your threads with Gmail service classes and get the messages received from the alarm system.

```
getMessagesForThread(thread)
```

you will be able to get new messages and compare their time.

```
GmailMessage.getDate()
```

select messages to send trash and trash them.

```
moveMessageToTrash(message)
```

All the methods and descriptions are available on [Google developer app script -Gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/)

Edit: You were comparing current date with start and end time.

`var actionToTake = now < endDate && now > startDate ? 'delete' : 'move';`

It should be message time. Also did some amendments to `dateObj` function. Refer the below code.

```
function MoveMsgBasedOnTime() 
{
  var Label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("2 - Scout");

  //Retrieve All Messages with Matching Label 
  var Threads = Label.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < Threads.length; i++) 
  {
    var Msgs = Threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j=0;j < Msgs.length ;j++)
    {
      var MsgTime = Msgs[j].getDate();
      //If Sunday (0) or Saturday (5)
      if (MsgTime.getDay() == 0 || MsgTime.getDay() == 6)
      {
        //Move To Inbox
        Threads[i].moveToInbox(); 
      }

      //If Monday(1), Tuesday (2), Wednesday (3), Thursday (4), Friday (5)
      if (MsgTime.getDay() == 1 || MsgTime.getDay() == 2 || MsgTime.getDay() == 3 || MsgTime.getDay() == 4 || MsgTime.getDay() == 5 )
      {
        var startTime = '8:00 AM';
        var endTime   = '7:30 PM';
        var startDate = dateObj(startTime,MsgTime);
        var endDate   = dateObj(endTime,MsgTime);

        var actionToTake = MsgTime < endDate && MsgTime > startDate ? 'delete' : 'move';

        //If Message Time is Between 8am and 6pm Take Action to Move to Trash
        if (actionToTake == "delete");
        {
        }

        //If Message Time is Before 8am or After 6pm Take Action to Move to Inbox
        if (actionToTake == "move")
        {
          Threads[i].removeLabel(Label);
          Threads[i].moveToInbox();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

//Function To Parse Time from Date for Comparisson using startTime & endTime variables above
function dateObj(d,MsgTime) 
{
  var parts = d.split(/:|\s/),
      date  = new Date(MsgTime);
  if (parts.pop().toLowerCase() == 'pm') parts[0] = (+parts[0]) + 12;
  date.setHours(+parts.shift());
  date.setMinutes(+parts.shift());
  return date;
}
```

Comment: Beta code has been updated in OP. Maybe someone can help with what I have?

Comment: -  Thank you very much, unfortunately this is not functioning properly. This ends up putting ALL threads (despite the time of the threads/messages) into the inbox after the endTime has passed.

I want all threads that have come in AFTER 7:30pm  or BEFORE 8:00am to hit the inbox, all others STAY in the Scout label, so that any of these alerts that hit the inbox are actually worth being notified for. @iJay